# Having issues setting up a simple filestream

Tags: c#

I am writing an application that allows the user to import a picture from the computer and view it in my application. The user also has an import button under the picture and he/she can select the picture's destination in the computer.

My problem is that I get following exception:

> System.IO.IOException: 'The process cannot access the file 'D:\Workspaces_Foo\Foo\Theme\MyPic.png' because it is being used by another process.'

when I debug it I find the line where it's breaking. It is in:

```
string image = Constants.ImageName;
if (image != "NONE")
{
   using (var stream = File.OpenRead(SourceDir + ImageName))
   {  
     Directory.CreateDirectory(Path.GetDirectoryName(DestinationDir + "\\" + image));

     File.Copy(SourceDir + "\\" + image, DestinationDir + "\\" + image, true); //breaks here...
   }                
 }
```

I assumed that by using a filestream it would've allowed me to continue with my picture transfer. Can anyone tell me why I am getting this error?

Comment: Have you tried reading the error message: `it is being used by another process`? This can mean two things: (A) the file is indeed used/locked by another process on your computer. You can use a tool like LockHunter to identify this other process. It can however also mean that (B) your own program has the file already opened (with another filestream, for example), and opened the file the first time without setting its FileShare attribute to FileShare.ReadWrite, which would make another attempt to open the already open file fail.

Comment: If it is case (B), you will need to debug your program to figure out how/why/where your program tries to open the file twice. Also, if you open the file only to read from it, then don't use FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.ReadWrite parameters. Simply use `File.OpenRead()`

Comment: @elgonzo I changed the filestream from File.Open to File.OpenRead() and that seemed to make the initial problem go away. Now I am getting the error when I call the File.Copy (see the updated code above in 2 minutes)

Comment: Your underlying problem is still there. Switching to File.OpenRead() allows to open the file twice, which still happens. Your real problem is in all likelihood some borked logic in your program that leads to the file being opened twice and that probably is also responsible for the error you see now. As i said, you need to debug your program thoroughly to hunt down the root of your problem...

Comment: Please try to understand your own source code in your (edited) question. Use the documentation to read up on what each line does. Do not rely on your own (probably false) assumptions when trying to understand what your code is actually doing. Using the debugger to step through and watch your code will help you get abetter understanding.

Comment: Last thing before i sign off here: Answer this question do yourself: Why do you open the image file (using File.OpenRead)? What purpose does it fulfill? (Cue assumption-based programming never works ;-P )

Comment: @elgonzo thank you. I will debug it some more and see what it is doing.

Comment: Hi @elgonzo, while the OP might be new and could benefit some one-on-one tutoring, this is a question and answer site. I figured a straight answer may be more effective.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are opening a stream for the file. This opens the file and marks it as in use.

Then you use File.Copy to copy it, but the Operating system says the file is in use (it isn't clever enough to notice that it is in use by your own process!)

Forget the stream, try this instead.

```
string image = Constants.ImageName;
if (image != "NONE")
{
    Directory.CreateDirectory(Path.GetDirectoryName(DestinationDir + "\\" + image));

    File.Copy(SourceDir + "\\" + image, DestinationDir + "\\" + image, true);
}
```